# Image Search API bing Retrofit not getting response

Tags: android, retrofit, bing-api

I am new to retrofit.Image Search API getting null response. while the response is successful but it still returns null.

This is the search interface where the query of the key is made

```
public interface BingApiService {


@Headers("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: *key*")
@GET("bing/v7.0/search")
Call<ImageSearch> getBingResponse(
         @Query("q") String q


);}
```

BingApiUtils

```
public class BingApiUtils {

private BingApiUtils() {
}

public static final String BASE_URL = "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/";

public static BingApiService getBingAPIService() {
    return BingRetrofitClient.getClient(BASE_URL).create(BingApiService.class);
}
```

}

```
getclient function

public class BingRetrofitClient {

private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

public static Retrofit getClient(String baseUrl) {
    if (retrofit == null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
```

}

```
    bingApiService.getBingResponse("cat").enqueue(new Callback<ImageSearch>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ImageSearch> call, Response<ImageSearch> response) {

 // here I get the null response
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ImageSearch> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: What is your subscription key? Want to test your code. You can change it later.

Comment: I have tried it  [here](https://dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/8336afba49a84475ba401758c0dbf749/operations/56b4433fcf5ff8098cef380c/console) . It's working fine.  but getting null as the response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image search endpoint seems to be incorrect. It should be: https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/images/search. You seem to be calling the web search API endpoint.

Comment: Yes I had figured it out. Thanks